# Fix unknown file system grub rescue> error

Tags: windows-10, grub, bootloader, boot-partition, bootrepair

When I boot normally, after the bios screen it shows

```
error : unknown file system
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>_
```

I think it's because, I deleted the Linux(which I used to dual boot) partition to get some free space. I deleted that through windows disk management tool and created a new empty partition. After that when I restarted, I'm getting this error.

I also tried checking each disk, by

```
ls
ls (hd0,msdos1)
...
```

For all the available disks.
But all returned :file system is unknown

I googled, and the only solution I found is to burn windows installation media to a usb and recover it that way. But it needs another PC which I don't have. To do it through my android phone, I don't have a mobile to usb cable, and can't get it now because of the lockdown here. And I can't even root my Xiaomi phone without pc.

But I have clover on a flashable usb. I tried installing hackintosh long ago, but it didn't work and I left the usb without formating. I don't think there's a way to install macos through that too. Because the usb is only filled 20-30MB (I know I did mess up something while trying to install hackintosh, that's why it failed and I didn't install it. My PC was working fine for months after that)
Through clover shell I can access files on HDD through `map -r`.

[Clover shell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEO4O.jpg)

[Other things on usb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qaohh.jpg)

Is there any way to boot windows from there. I also have a RecoveryHDupdate.pkg of macos somewhere on the hdd, if that can help to install macos .I also have a Linux iso image on the hdd. Is there any way to boot up any OS now, so that I can further burn windows recovery to usb.
Clover shell is the only thing I have acces to, right now.

Please help.

Comment: did you install the windows OS on the computer (laptop?) or is it OEM Windows?

Comment: @Andra I installed it. However it is a legacy install.